# creating multiple files from a same worksheet VBA

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

In a file named `FILE` I have the following piece of code, which, among other stuff, fills in a table for each part defined in the sheet, and then saves a pdf file containing the part in the name, to be named `FILEPART.pdf`.

```
'parts
lastRow = Sheets("overview").Range("G1000").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowHere = Sheets("Source").Range("A13:A1000").End(xlUp).Row
'count of parts
Count = lastRowHere + 2
For m = 1 To Count    
    For n = 14 To lastRow
        Partname = Sheets("overview").Range("C" & n) & 
        _" of " & Sheets("overview").Range("A" & n)
       [...]
    Next n
    'creates the PDF file for mapping on each part
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    If FSO.FileExists(s(0)) Then
        '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
        s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))
        If s(1) <> "" Then
            s(1) = "." & s(1)
            sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), Partname & ".pdf")

            '//Export to PDF with new File Path
            lastPart = Sheets("table").Cells(1000, m * 5 + 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets("table").Range(Cells(1, m * 5 + 1), Cells(lastPart, m * 5 + 5)).
            _ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=sNewFilePath, 
            _Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, 
            _IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        End If
    Else
        '//Error: file path not found
        MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
    End If
    Set FSO = Nothing
Next m
```

My problem is that I get a single file, and not multiple ones with different names.
Going step by step throught the loop I see that first it creates `FILEPART1.pdf`, then replace it with `FILEPART2.pdf`, ending with only `FILEPARTLAST.pdf`

Comment: The best way to diagnose a failing loop if not obvious is to step through the routine and watch it work. I assume you've checked that `Count` isn't set to `1` at the start of the above? I'm also confused as to why you set and test `s(0)` inside your loop as based on the code you've provided, it shouldn't change.

Comment: @CLR, see the edit. I have gone into the loop step by step

Comment: What is your `n` loop for? Looks to me as if `Partname` will always have the same value. Agree with @CLR that you can take a good chunk out of your loop.

Comment: Also you have `lastRowHere` and `lastRow` - intentional?

Comment: @SJR, yes, that's intentional. The n loops through the overview, while the m loop through parts

Comment: Unless I am missing something, in each iteration of your m loop, Partname will end up with the value of `Partname = Sheets("overview").Range("C" & n) & " of " & Sheets("overview").Range("A" & n)` where `n=lastrow`, i.e. the same value.

Comment: you are right, I checked with `MsgBox (sNewFilePath)`

Comment: Now the problem has changed (see edit)

Comment: I think you should post a separate question. If you are changing the code in your OP then anyone visiting this in the future will not see the code which exhibited the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the code (after SJR's comments) solved the issue

```
'parts
lastRow = Sheets("overview").Range("G1000").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowHere = Sheets("Source").Range("A13:A1000").End(xlUp).Row
'count of parts
Count = lastRowHere + 2
s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName
For m = 1 To Count    
    PartNameSource = Sheets("Source").Range("A" & m + 13)
    For n = 14 To lastRow
        PartnameLine = Sheets("overview").Range("C" & n) & 
        _" of " & Sheets("overview").Range("A" & n)
       [...]
    Next n
    'creates the PDF file for mapping on each part
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If FSO.FileExists(s(0)) Then
        '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
        s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))
        If s(1) <> "" Then
            s(1) = "." & s(1)
            sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), PartnameSource & ".pdf")

            '//Export to PDF with new File Path
            lastPart = Sheets("table").Cells(1000, m * 5 + 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets("table").Range(Cells(1, m * 5 + 1), Cells(lastPart, m * 5 + 5)).
            _ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=sNewFilePath, 
            _Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, 
            _IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        End If
    Else
        '//Error: file path not found
        MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
    End If
    Set FSO = Nothing
Next m
```

**REMARK**

If `PartNameSource` contains characters which make the file name invalid (like `/`) there will be a `run-time error 1004 Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving`